# IronOCR / Tesseract OCR recognize single digit

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I want to use IronOCR to recognize single digits from a screenshot.

The problem is, that my .Read() Result always ends up as an empty "".

This is my code

```
        var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(105,
        25,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

        var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(992,
        400,
        0,
        0,
        new Size(105, 25),
        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        var ocrInput = new IronOcr.OcrInput(bmpScreenshot);
        ocrInput.EnhanceResolution();
        ocrInput.Contrast();
        ocrInput.Invert();

        var Ocr = new IronOcr.IronTesseract();
        Ocr.Configuration.WhiteListCharacters = "0123456789";

        var Result = Ocr.Read(ocrInput).Text;
```

Example screenshot used for the recognition

[image]

If I want to recognize 2 or more digits it works fine (most of the time).

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md?

Comment: It helped me with overall accuracy by using

 Ocr.Configuration.WhiteListCharacters = "0123456789";
 Ocr.Configuration.TesseractVariables.Add("load_system_dawg", false);
 Ocr.Configuration.TesseractVariables.Add("load_freq_dawg", false);

however, I am still struggling with detecting single digits.

Comment: In referenced docs, there are instructions on how to solve your problem. Just read it and follow.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for Iron Software.

If you are always expecting single characters, try setting the  TesseractPageSegmentationMode to SingleChar, which treats the image as a single character.

```
Ocr.Configuration.PageSegmentationMode = TesseractPageSegmentationMode.SingleChar;
```

Otherwise our engineers tested your example, and saw a successful result with the following [image filters](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/examples/ocr-image-filters-for-net-tesseract/).

Code example:

```
var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.Financial;
using (var Input = new OcrInput(@"F:\input.png"))
{
    Input.DeNoise();
    Input.Invert();
    //Input.DeepCleanBackgroundNoise();
    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
    Console.WriteLine(Result.Text);
}
```

Small note that DeepCleanBackgroundNoise() is very CPU intensive as it performs heavy background noise removal. Only use for extreme document background noise.

Comment: I tried but not works, even with binarisation filter (black and white img). It fails.